# How would I set the link state to remain until the user visits another page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigationbar

I'm wondering how I could make it so a button on my navigation bar stays active (in this case, a different background color) while the user remains on that page, switching when they visit another page so they know where they are at all times?

Is it something simple that I'm not aware of or would it require some JavaScript or the like?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Are you using any kind of backend or just static HTML pages?

Comment: Just static HTML. It's a new project, and I'm still learning :)

Comment: You mean something like a "breadcrumb"?  See: [Bootstrap - Breadcrumbs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#breadcrumbs)

Comment: So in each page add "active" class to different item in the nav.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean this effect?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <style>
            .title{
                float: left;
                background-color: #51D7FF;
                margin-right: 10px;
                width: 80px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .current{
                background: #4DFFE4;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var myDate = new Date();
                $('.title1').addClass('current');
                $('.title').click(function(){
                    $(this).addClass('current');
                    $(this).siblings().removeClass('current');
                }); 
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="title title1">title1</div>
        <div class="title title2">title2</div>
        <div class="title title3">title3</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is this saved for when the user enters another static HTML page? I think you will need to set cookies or try something else.

Comment: @Aziz Maybe it can use Ajax :)